# how to open IDM using PHP

Tags: php

i want to open internet download manager using exec() function in PHP and here is my code :

```
if(isset($_POST['link'])){
    exec('C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Download Manager\IDMan.exe /d '.$_POST['link']);.......
```

but nothing happens with this script . so is there something wrong with my code ?
thanks in advance .

Comment: If you print out the command and run it in eg. `cmd.exe` does it work fine? You might try to use `proc_open` instead so you can read `stdin` and `stderr`.

Comment: does php have access/permission to run that exe? are you running this under a webserver (usually can't open console apps from a service), etc... Plus pasting user-provided data into an exec() call like that is just getting to get your server trashed. consider `link=&& shutdown /r /t 0` as the parameter.

Comment: all other commands e.g. "ping 4.2.2.4" are totally work and prints out fine , the only problem is whit running the IDM and i don't know why .